# Word for "percentage of elements changed"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a table that shows the number of elements added, deleted, and changed in a graph.  I'm calling the sum of additions + deletions + changes the "differences."  I also want to include a column that shows the "percentage of elements that are different"--for simplicity, let's say this percentage is the number of differences divided by the total number of elements.

My first thought is to call this *percent different* or *difference percentage* or *modification factor* but it seems like there should be a more commonly-used term for this.  I also considered *percent changed* but since "change" has a specific technical meaning in this table I can't use that.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I feel that if you put *percentage* into the title of it when that is going to be shown by the actual value, it may feel a bit redundant.

Maybe consider something like *Adjusted Proportion* or *Affected/Altered Portion*.

This will be slightly influenced by the data your presenting since you said 'Change' is already reserved for another meaning. Hopefully that gets the feeling across that it is a slice of changes, shown by the *X*%.

Comment: I like "percent altered."

Comment: I agree including *percentage* in the title seems redundant.

Answer (score 1):

**Delta** is commonly used to express change or amount of change. If you want to express the change as a percentage, use the percent symbol after the numerical values. Or you can use *% Delta* or *Delta %* as a column header.

The greek capital letter for delta may also be used, if space is a problem. (Sorry, I don't have a keyboard that I can type that with at the moment.)

Comment: Delta would be a better match for "sum of additions + deletions + changes."

Comment: But % delta would adress the op's need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  The delta character would be perfect if we hadn't already used it in many places to denote a "changed" element. (D'oh!)